# How to update cordova platform android@6.2.3 to android@8.0.0?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic1 cordova projects. In that projects we using cordova platform android@6.2.3.So,What are the Requirements need to update my **cordova platforms Android@8.0.0?** .

and

```
ionic info
```

cli packages: (C:\Windows\System32\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.11.3
npm               : 6.1.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

How to resolve it.

Answer (score 5):

First I would recommend to **remove** Android platform

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

Second just enter the code below and type the desired platform version after **@**.
For example:

```
ionic cordova platform add android@7.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest cordova-platform android version is 7.1.0 Till date 27 june 2018

Which supports API level 19 - 27 means android 4.4 - 8.0

See this https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/

use command for the lastest cordova-platform

```
>>    ionic cordova platform add android@7.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

### For api level 28 or 8+

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@8.1
```

[For More Details](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)